# How can I deserialize my JSON string?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a serialized JSON string

```
string json = " [
                {
                    \"id\": 1,
                    \"barcode\": \"TestBARCODE\",
                    \"nsr\": 0,
                    \"stk_in\": 0,
                    \"stk_out\": 0,
                    \"sales\": 0,
                    \"balance\": 1
                },
                {
                    \"id\": 2,
                    \"barcode\": \"TestBARCODE2\",
                    \"nsr\": 0,
                    \"stk_in\": 0,
                    \"stk_out\": 0,
                    \"sales\": 0,
                    \"balance\": 1
                },
                {
                    \"id\": 3,
                    \"barcode\": \"TestBARCODE3\",
                    \"nsr\": 0,
                    \"stk_in\": 0,
                    \"stk_out\": 0,
                    \"sales\": 0,
                    \"balance\": 1
                },
                {
                    \"id\": 4,
                    \"barcode\": \"AAA\",
                    \"nsr\": 0,
                    \"stk_in\": 0,
                    \"stk_out\": 0,
                    \"sales\": 0,
                    \"balance\": 1
                },
                {
                    \"id\": 5,
                    \"barcode\": \"BBB\",
                    \"nsr\": 0,
                    \"stk_in\": 0,
                    \"stk_out\": 0,
                    \"sales\": 0,
                    \"balance\": 1
                }
            ]"
```

I need to iterate each line getting the id, barcode, nsr, etc and their values. I am using Newtonsoft but can't use their example `Movie m = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Movie>(json);`

I tried `var m = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JValue>(json);` It does get return the JSON line. For somereason m.Value is a string type. Any ideas how I can iterate this?

Comment: Does `DeserializeObject<Movie>` work if you pass in just one object (not the whole array)?

Comment: @NateBarbettini: If you want to reformat the JSON, please make sure that the C# code is still valid (by using `@"..."` syntax, e.g.)

Comment: @StriplingWarrior thanks for the catch!

Comment: @NateBarbettini: Unfortunately, your edit still breaks C#, since `@""` syntax uses `""` to escape quotes rather than `\"`.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior Wow, I need a break. :( Haha

Comment: Guys, the line with Movie object was just an example I used from JSON.NET's web page.

Answer (score 1):

In Addition to @StriplingWarriors solution: I guess your declaration of `Movie` doesn't fit the json string. Define your class like the following:

```
// tip: use a tool like http://json2csharp.com/ to avoid typos etc.
public class MyObject
{
    public int id {get;set;}
    public string barcode {get;set;}
    public int nsr {get;set;}
    public int stk_in {get;set;}
    public int stk_out {get;set;}
    public int sales {get;set;}
    public int balance {get;set;}
}
```

And then deserialize your json into a `List` of your class like so:

```
var m = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyObject>>(json);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the json string defined in your example represent collection so you have to deserialize to List. I have created [this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/3IdaCr) dotnet fiddle to demonstrate your scenario. You can check the output in fiddle.

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string json = "[{\"id\":1,\"barcode\":\"TestBARCODE\",\"nsr\":0,\"stk_in\":0,\"stk_out\":0,\"sales\":0,\"balance\":1},{\"id\":2,\"barcode\":\"TestBARCODE2\",\"nsr\":0,\"stk_in\":0,\"stk_out\":0,\"sales\":0,\"balance\":1},{\"id\":3,\"barcode\":\"TestBARCODE3\",\"nsr\":0,\"stk_in\":0,\"stk_out\":0,\"sales\":0,\"balance\":1},{\"id\":4,\"barcode\":\"AAA\",\"nsr\":0,\"stk_in\":0,\"stk_out\":0,\"sales\":0,\"balance\":1},{\"id\":5,\"barcode\":\"BBB\",\"nsr\":0,\"stk_in\":0,\"stk_out\":0,\"sales\":0,\"balance\":1}]";
        var movies = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Movie>>(json);
        foreach (var movie in movies)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Movie Id : " + movie.Id + " BarCode : " + movie.Barcode);
        }
    }

}

public class Movie
{
    public int Id {get; set; }
    public string Barcode {get; set; }
    public int NSR {get; set; }


    public int Stk_in {get; set; }
    public int Stk_out {get; set; }

    public int Balance {get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`JValue`s can only represent primitive values like strings and numbers, so when you deserialize a string into a JValue, it makes sense that it would become a `string`-backed value.

Try this instead:

```
var m = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JArray>(json);
```

Then:

```
foreach(var item in m)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item["id"]);
    ...
}
```

Comment: I have tried that as well and it returned an exception  Unable to cast object of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue' to type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray'.

Comment: @JoshuaMasangcay: I find that hard to believe, considering I have [a working example](http://share.linqpad.net/brnn2q.linq). It sounds like you tried *casting* the result to a `JArray` instead of telling `DeserializeObject<>()` that you wanted a `JArray` in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class Data
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string barcode { get; set; }
    public int nsr { get; set; }
    public int stk_in { get; set; }
    public int stk_out { get; set; }
    public int sales { get; set; }
    public int balance { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Data> data { get; set; }
}   

RootObject objRootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
if (objRootObject.data.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (var item in objRootObject.data)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item.id);
        Console.WriteLine(item.barcode);
        Console.WriteLine(item.nsr);
    }
}
```

This is really definitely helpful to you.